# Qt signal/slots - consume signal in one of many slots?

Tags: qt, signals, slot

Is there a way to consume future slots (and stop them from executing) in one of many slots connected to the same signal?

My goal here is to emit a signal with a message to many QObjects and consume (stopping iteration to future slots) when the QObject in which the message belongs to finds it.

From what I understand in the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html):

> If several slots are connected to one signal, the slots will be
> executed one after the other, in the order they have been connected,
> when the signal is emitted.

I want to be able to stop this process from within a slot.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do it, and you should not think of it this way. The sender should perform the same no matter what number of slots are connected to a signal. That's the basic contract of the signal-slot mechanism: the sender is completely decoupled from, and unaware of, the receiver.

What you're trying to do is qualified dispatch: there are multiple receivers, and each receiver can process one or more message types. One way of implementing it is as follows:

1. Emit (signal) a `QEvent`. This lets you maintain the signal-slot decoupling between the transmitter and the receiver(s).
2. The event can then be consumed by a custom event dispatcher that knows which objects process events of given type.
3. The objects are sent the event in the usual fashion, and receive it in their `event()` method.

The implementation below allows the receiver objects to live in other threads. That's why it needs to be able to clone events.

```
class <QCoreApplication>
class <QEvent>

class ClonableEvent : public QEvent {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(ClonableEvent)
public:
  ClonableEvent(int type) : QEvent(static_cast<QEvent::Type>(type)) {}
  virtual ClonableEvent * clone() const { return new ClonableEvent(type()); }
}
Q_REGISTER_METATYPE(ClonableEvent*)

class Dispatcher : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QMap<int, QSet<QObject*>> m_handlers;
public:
  Q_SLOT void dispatch(ClonableEvent * ev) {
    auto it = m_handlers.find(ev->type());
    if (it == m_handlers.end()) return;
    for (auto object : *it) {
      if (obj->thread() == QThread::currentThread())
        QCoreApplication::sendEvent(obj, ev);
      else
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(obj, ev.clone());
    }
  }
  void addMapping(QClonableEvent * ev, QObject * obj) { 
    addMapping(ev->type(), obj);
  }
  void addMapping(int type, QObject * obj) {
    QSet<QObject*> & handlers = m_handlers[type];
    auto it = handlers.find(obj);
    if (it != handlers.end()) return;
    handlers.insert(obj);
    QObject::connect(obj, &QObject::destroyed, [this, type, obj]{
      unregister(type, obj);
    });
    m_handlers[type].insert(obj);
  }
  void removeMapping(int type, QObject * obj) {
    auto it = m_handlers.find(type);
    if (it == m_handlers.end()) return;
    it->remove(obj);
  }
}

class EventDisplay : public QObject {
  bool event(QEvent * ev) {
    qDebug() << objectName() << "got event" << ev.type();
    return QObject::event(ev);
  }
public:
  EventDisplay() {}
};

class EventSource : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void indication(ClonableEvent *);
}

#define NAMED(x) x; x.setObjectName(#x)
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);
  ClonableEvent ev1(QEvent::User + 1);
  ClonableEvent ev2(QEvent::User + 2);
  EventDisplay NAMED(dp1);
  EventDisplay NAMED(dp12);
  EventDisplay NAMED(dp2);

  Dispatcher d;
  d.addMapping(ev1, dp1);  // dp1 handles only ev1
  d.addMapping(ev1, dp12); // dp12 handles both ev1 and ev2
  d.addMapping(ev2, dp12);
  d.addMapping(ev2, dp2);  // dp2 handles only ev2

  EventSource s;
  QObject::connect(&s, &EventSource::indication, &d, &Dispatcher::dispatch);

  emit s.indication(&ev1);
  emit s.indication(&ev2);
  return 0;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: TODO: This code is not thread-safe in face of object deletion in other threads. This is fixable.

Answer (score 0):

If connection was in one thread, I think that you can throw an exception. But in this case you should be catch any exception during emit a signal:

```
try {
    emit someSignal();
} catch(...) {
    qDebug() << "catched";
}
```

But I think that it's bad idea. I'll would be use event dispatching for this.